# does jq --stream run in background?

Tags: stream, jq

I ran the below-mentioned jq command and my putty session became inactive. however, I can still see the process running using the "top" command.

Does jq --stream run in background by default?

```
jq -cn --stream '
  fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "userActivities") | del(.[0][0])))
  | select(.localDate[0:7] == "2018-10")
' 2018-10-01T21_45_56Z_triplem-baas_data.json > October_2018_triplem_events.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does jq --stream run in background by default?

No.

The --stream option is usually only used for very large JSON texts, so if that is the case here, then it might take a long while for the job to finish. If you want to verify that progress is being made, consider adding one or more `debug` statements: each `debug` is like `.` but copies its input value to STDERR before passing the value along.

Sometimes it pays to be a bit devious with `debug`, as illustrated in this variant of your program:

```
jq -cn --stream '
  fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "userActivities") | del(.[0][0])))
  | (.localDate|debug) as $debug
  | select(.localDate[0:7] == "2018-10")
' 2018-10-01T21_45_56Z_triplem-baas_data.json > October_2018_triplem_events.json
```